# Why can't I receive a message from my remote public transactional queue?

Tags: c#, msmq, msdtc, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm using C# on Windows Server 2008, and I want to receive a message from a public transactional queue on another machine in the same domain.  The error looks like this:

```
System.Messaging.MessageQueueException: Cannot import the transaction.
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveCurrent(TimeSpan timeout, Int32 action, CursorHandle cursor, MessagePropertyFilter filter, MessageQueueTransaction internalTransaction, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Receive(TimeSpan timeout, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
   at JobManagerLib.JobProcessor.Process(Action waitForNewMessageCallback) in C:\Dev\OtherProjects\POC\WindowsService\JobManagerSample\JobManagerLib\JobProcessor.cs:line 132
```

I've tried DTCPing, which succeeds in one direction but fails in the other.  Here is the pertinent part of the log:

```
++++++++++++hosts      ++++++++++++
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost

08-20, 15:47:22.739-->Error(0x424) at clutil.cpp @256
08-20, 15:47:22.739-->-->OpenCluster
08-20, 15:47:22.739-->-->1060(The specified service does not exist as an installed service.)
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
     DTCping 1.9 Report for DEV-MSMQ2  
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
RPC server is ready
++++++++++++Validating Remote Computer Name++++++++++++
08-20, 15:47:26.207-->Start DTC connection test
Name Resolution:
    dev-msmq1-->192.168.22.11-->Dev-msmq1
08-20, 15:47:26.222-->Start RPC test (DEV-MSMQ2-->dev-msmq1)
RPC test failed
```

Does anybody have any idea why this might be failing?  The Windows Firewall has been opened for MSDTC.  It's hard to find much info about Windows 2008 and MSMQ.

**EDIT**: The queue names are FormatName:DIRECT=OS:dev-msmq1\getmap, and FormatName:DIRECT=OS:dev-msmq1\logevent.  They are public, transactional queues, and Everyone has peek/receive permission on them.  The pertinent part of my code is as follows:

```
using (TransactionScope tx = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    using (var queue = new MessageQueue(QueueName))
    {
        queue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new string[] { _targetParameterType });
        var message = queue.Receive(TimeOut, MessageQueueTransactionType.Automatic);
        string messageId = message.Label;

...
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe post your code or your queue configuration. MSMQ can be picky on the formatting of the queue name.

Comment: But what the are the actual names? (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778392(WS.10).aspx). Though I do think it relates to the transactions. (MSDTC). Never used that though. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry...queue names that are being used here are FormatName:DIRECT=OS:dev-msmq1\SendEmail and FormatName:DIRECT=OS:dev-msmq1\LogEvent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did find a solution: abandon the whole thing altogether and switch to using WCF and the net.Msmq binding.  Now the queue communication is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, both machine's clocks are in sync. I seen this before where authentication will fail because the server and the client are off time by a minute. This will happen even if the queues are public and have permissions on everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, allowing only MSDTC and MSMQ through the firewall is not enough when running IPv4:

You need to let ICMP traffic through the firewall as well (IPv6 can resolve host names regardless of the firewall, but your DTCPIng log indicates you are running IPv4).

I have struggled with the same error you see in DTCPing, and in my case it turned out to be triggered by the firewall blocking the ICMP traffic.